# Can Moqui implement a form with dynamic fields

Tags: moqui

I have two list `listRowKey` and `listColKey` and a nested map `map<Row, Map<Col, String>>`, I want to create a table to input content into map, the rows and cols of table is generated from two list. I don't known how to use a nested loop to add fields into form.

Answer (score 0):

The XML Forms in Moqui are not designed for this sort of thing. I have implemented a number of screens with Moqui that need a dynamic set of columns and the best approach for that is to use an FTL template under the render-mode element, see the Making Apps with Moqui book for examples and details on how to use it. The FTL template can be embedded in the screen XML file or put in a separate file.

Comment: Maybe I don't need a form with dynamic field name. I just need a `form-grid` widget. I am looking at the `DefaultScreenMacros.html.ftl`